# Very weird error after import .OBJ

Tags: import, error, obj

I sometimes get this error while importing an large .OBJ file. The Mesh is completely broken. Can someone help me, please?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Might be helpful to ask people for more advice on how to best import an .OBJ file. They might have some good tips for you, and it would also help other users. To include a Blend file go to :blend-exchange.com. I have sometimes noticed changing the scene units can help just in case there is a mismatch.

Comment: @common_goldfish: How to best....is a very bad question here, because you shouldn't ask opinioned based questions, because that kind of questions will be closed quickly.

Comment: @Chris:  Fair enough, hopefully the OP gets back to us with either info on his import settings or a .blend.